# MultiValueDictKeyError when submitting ModelFormSet

Tags: python, django, django-forms

When trying to submit my ModelFormSet I am getting a MultiValueDictKeyError. The error message is not very descriptive so I'm not sure why the error is being thrown.

Here is the view:

```
def admin_tools(request):
    ElectionFormSet = modelformset_factory(Election, exclude=('Complete',), formset=BaseElectionFormSet, extra=0)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'new_election' in request.POST:
            new_election = NewElectionForm(request.POST)
            if new_election.is_valid():
                election = new_election.save(commit=False)
                election.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Election created')
                return redirect(reverse('elections:home'))
        elif 'edit_elections' in request.POST:
            formset = ElectionFormSet(request.POST)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Election settings saved')
                return redirect(reverse('elections:home'))
    else:
        new_election_form = NewElectionForm()
        formset = ElectionFormSet()

    return render(request, 'admin/admin_tools.html',{
        'new_election': new_election_form,
        'formset': formset,
    })
```

Here is the relevant section of the template:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <h4>Toggle election settings:</h4>
    <form method="post" action="">

        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-body w-75 mx-auto'>

                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-6 text-center'>
                            <p>Name<br>{{form.Name}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-6 text-center'>
                            <p>Videos<br>{{form.FlipGrid}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-12 text-center'>
                            <p>Description<br>{{form.Description}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-6 text-center'>
                            <p>Allow registration: {{form.CandidateReg}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-6 text-center'>
                            <p>Allow voting: {{form.VotingOpen}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class='text-center'>
            <br><button type="submit" class='btn btn-outline-dark' name='edit_elections'>Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The error is `raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'form-0-id'"`

and it was flagged on the line: `if formset.is_valid():` of the view.

How do I resolve this error and get the formset to correctly submit and update the data in the model?

Comment: @internet_user ok, do you know what dictionary that is a key in and how do I stop the error from happening?

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980475/multivaluedictkeyerror-in-django-modelformset-factory

Comment: @neverwalkaloner thanks that helped. Problem now solved.